# Printing the numbers after match (bash)

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a script (with bash) that looks for a word (for example "E( ENERGY) =") and prints the rest of the line which is effectively some numbers with "-" in front. To clarify, an example line that I'm looking for in a file is;

`MOST-DESIRED RESULT E(   ENERGY) =       -9.68765465413`

All I need is -9.68765465413 to be printed.
I've managed to print the whole line, but this is rather ineffective for me. The script that I have in hand up to this point is as follows (named script.sh):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

output="$1" 
ext="log"
word="E(   ENERGY)"
find "$output" -type f -name "*.$ext" -exec grep -wFnH "$word" {} +
```

And I loop this script in another script (run_script.sh) for the files in a folder to look at all the files I have. And my current output looks like this;

```
RESULT1_DH.log:567: MOST-DESIRED RESULT E(   ENERGY) =       -1.0501552997
RESULT2.log:567: MOST-DESIRED RESULT E(   ENERGY) =       -1.0501552997
```

But I want it to look like this;

```
RESULT1_DH.log        -1.0501552997
RESULT2.log        -1.0501552997
```

If anyone can help me with this, I'll be grateful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample inputs:

```
$ head RESULT*log
==> RESULT1_DH.log <==
MOST-DESIRED RESULT E(   ENERGY) =       -1.0501552997
MOST-DESIRED RESULT E(   POWER) =       -9.9999999999

==> RESULT2.log <==
MOST-DESIRED RESULT E(   ENERGY) =       -1.0501552997
MOST-DESIRED RESULT E(   POWER) =       -9.9999999999
```

One `awk` idea:

```
output='.'
ext='log'
word="E(   ENERGY)"
find "${output}" -type f -name "*.${ext}" -exec awk -v ptn="${word}" 'index($0,ptn) {print FILENAME,$NF}' {} +
```

This generates:

```
./RESULT1_DH.log -1.0501552997
./RESULT2.log -1.0501552997
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your answer, this helped me greatly! Just a quick question, when my target word has only the number I need after it, this works. But when I change the target word that has something like `WORD:  -9.68765465413    ANOTHER WORD:  -1231.5454` how can I extract the number after WORD? When I use this code while using WORD, it extracts the number after "ANOTHER WORD". Thanks again!

Comment: you're basically asking a new question ... completely different format of the input data, desired data is not limited to the last field in the line, word/value delimiter changed from `=` to `:`; I'd suggest asking a new question and this time provide multiple samples that more accurately match your data and search requirements

Comment: @Alert please add the `WORD: ... ANOTHER WORD: ...` example to your [latest question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72005990) making sure to explain how we should determine which entry to use if we search on the single word `WORD` and end up with multiple matches in a single line